# strncpy() fails on second call for same source

Tags: c, string, windows, c-strings

I'm new with c and want to separate string in two parts. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void test(char** a, char** b)
{
  const char * c = "abcdef";

  *a = (char *)malloc(4* sizeof(char));
  *b = (char *)malloc(4* sizeof(char));


  strncpy(*a, c, 3);

  *a[3] = '\0';

  fprintf(stderr, "a -> %s\n", *a);



  strncpy(*b, c+3, 3);

  *b[3] = '\0';

  fprintf(stderr, "b -> %s\n", *b);

}

int main()
{
setvbuf (stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
char *a = NULL;
char *b  = NULL;

test(&a, &b);

fprintf(stderr, "a -> %s\n", *a);
fprintf(stderr, "b -> %s\n", *b);
}
```

I want to have `abc` on `a` variable and `def` in variable `b`. But my problem is that it fails with `Segmentation Fault`. After I run this I get this output:

```
a -> abc
Segmentation fault
```

I can't understand why. I'm using `cygwin` and build it with command

`gcc test.cpp -o test.exe`

Sorry if question sounds silly. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array-subscript-operator `[]` has higher precedence then the dereferencing operator `*`.

So you want to change

```
*a[3] = ...
```

to be

```
(*a)[3] = ...
```

Same for `b`.

---

Having set the compiler's warning level high enough, it should have warned you about this. Or at least told you that their is something fishy with

```
*a[3] = '\0';
```

Comment: Note that `a[0][3]` would also work, without worrying about parentheses.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: "*without worrying about parentheses*" same number of additional parentheses/brackets and still one character (`0`) more to type ... ;-)

Comment: @alk: Parentheses are *totally* different from brackets, at least in American English. ;-)